# How does Google keep its Geolocation database up-to-date?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, wifi, geocoding

I understand that Google used a wardriving kit in its Street View cars to bootstrap its map of wifi beacon landmarks.

But which data sources and methods do they use to discover and register new access points? Will they only feed in new BSSIDs submitted my Android phones with a valid GPS fix?

I set up two new APs (one of them dual 2.4/5GHz) and within two weeks Google had a fix for them, albeit 290m away from the real location. I will see if this fix will become more precise with time.

I’m fascinated by this but I didn’t find more details about how they do it.